# Algorithm: How to Sort elements of matrix with space constraint

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to understand the best possible way to solve this based on the constraints that are given. We have a matrix of numbers where each row is sorted. Our result should list all these elements in sorted order.

Example:

```
Input:  
20  40  80  
5   60  90  
45  50  55     
output:
5 20 40 45 50 55 60 80 90
```

Constraint : You are only allowed to hold 1 row at a time
Possible Solutions:
1) Use array, put all elements in array and sort them -> o(n) space for array and o(n log n) time for sorting. But this used extra memory so the constraint is really not getting fulfilled.

2) Use priority queue. Put all elements in priority queue and remove to get elements in sorted order. Again this uses o(n) space but we have better time complexity i.e. o(log n)

I am not able to understand the fact that how we can solve it with given constraint. Can someone please advise if I am missing something. It looks difficult to solve it with the given constraint.

Comment: Is there any constraint for time?

Comment: What does "you are only allowed to hold 1 row at a time" mean? As in, I can't keep switching between row? Because if you can, you can do this in O(nk) where n is the number of entries in the matrix and k is the number of rows.

Comment: Nothing is mentioned for the time but space is specifically mentioned.

Comment: you can have extra memory for putting 1 row at a time and you can switch between the rows. But I am assuming the fact that every row is sorted should be used somewhere to optimize this solution.

Comment: Is this ok if we use the extra memory for column, not row?

Comment: That was not specified. You can only store 1 row at a time. Plus the row is sorted so that can lead to some solution but I am not able to guess what that can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a priority queue. The size of this queue should be size of rows you have.
Then, insert fist elements from each row firstly.
Secondly, retrieve min value from priority queue, then insert a new element from the same line that the element you just retrieved comes from.
Thirdly, keep doing this, you get your result.

This does have a caveat though. Your constraint is keep space with in size of column. here I use space of size of row.  But I think this is fair.

Think about this, if you have 2 columns and 1M rows, using an array with size 2 won't help at all.

Comment: BufBills I do understand your solution. It took me some time to understand what you said but this still does not address the constraint. I agree that using array of size2 won't help if we have 1 M rows though. I am still thinking if we have a better solution. Your solution is obviously better than the what I listed specially with the space.